# Get variable outside method execute query MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I am implementing the Watson Conversation service with mysql, but I have a doubt in the `app.js` file. When I put one variable workspace side and I get it, I change the variable for the input of the user. However, when I implement the query for seek the user, I put a global variable to get the value of the query that I am calling for the response. Here is the code:

```
if(payload.context.name!='undefined'&&payload.context.nam!='undefined'&&payload.context.nam==false){
    payload.context.nam=true;
    payload.context.name=payload.input.text;
    console.log('nam'+payload.context.nam);
    console.log('name'+payload.context.name);    var queryUsers="Select Nombre from conversation_mabe.usuarios where Nombre='"+payload.input.text+"';";


    con.query(queryUsers, function(err, results) {

        for (var i in results) {
          nombre=results[i].Nombre;
        }
        console.log('query'+nombre)
      });
      console.log('nombre'+nombre)
      if(nombre==payload.context.name&&nombre!='undefined'){
           return res.json({
            'output': {
              'text': 'Su usuario es  '+nombre+' en que le puedo ayudar?'
           }
         });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do.  It looks like you are using the user's input question to look up in a database as a key.

However, one thing to know about callbacks in NodeJS is that they happen after the rest of the code in the calling scope.

```
con.query(queryUsers, function(err, results) {

    for (var i in results) {
      nombre=results[i].Nombre;
    }
    console.log('query'+nombre)
  });
  console.log('nombre'+nombre)
```

That second console.log will happen before the query callback function is fired.  If you want to do something with nombre, you will need to do it **inside** the callback function.